# Date Time Picker in calendar form in Cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, datetimepicker

I am building a cordova application. I want a date time picker in calendar format. Do anyone of you know about any plugin available?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use jquery mobile framework. You will get date time picker by default.

Comment: refer this http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/datepicker/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229087/how-to-implement-the-date-picker-in-phonegap-android

Comment: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: I am using jQuery mobile too. But I need date picker in form of calendar. But what is visible to me is in form of spinner.

Comment: Calendar plugin is for defining events. But I need date picker

Answer (score 0):

check this small [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/Navneethk/vreoq7zs/1/). It is created with jqueryui.